# Kendo Grid ClientFooterTemplate design

Tags: css, asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My current client footer template looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDkyz.png):

[image: Image 1]

But I need it to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF5WI.png):

[image: Image 2]

So I basically want to get rid of the lines that are being put in for each column in the kendo grid. Does anyone know how to do this?

To generate the client footer template I use the following code:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.BonusAwarded).ClientTemplate("#: '£' # #: BonusAwarded #").Width(100).ClientFooterTemplate("£ #= sum #");

.Aggregates(agg =>
    {
        agg.Add(a => a.BonusAwarded).Sum();
    })
```